# Calling a method on a value inside a mutable Option

Tags: rust

I have a mutable `Option` type and I'm trying to mutate the thing inside the `Some` but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::io::Write;

struct Foo {
    stream: Option<TcpStream>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn send(&mut self) {
        self.stream.map(|x| x.write(b"test")).expect("Couldn't write");
    }
}
```

This produces the error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable argument `x` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:10:29
   |
10 |         self.stream.map(|x| x.write(b"test")).expect("Couldn't write");
   |                          -  ^ cannot borrow mutably
   |                          |
   |                          consider changing this to `mut x`
```

Can someone try to implement `send` as an example to help me understand?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As [Vladimir Matveev points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27365182/155423), `if let` is even nicer, and is **more idiomatic** than iterating over the `Option`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    stream: Option<i32>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn send(&mut self) {
        if let Some(ref mut x) = self.stream {
            *x += 1;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = Foo { stream: Some(0) };
    println!("{:?}", f);

    f.send();
    println!("{:?}", f);
}
```

As of Rust 1.26, match ergonomics allows you to omit some of the keywords:

```
impl Foo {
    fn send(&mut self) {
        if let Some(x) = &mut self.stream {
            *x += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Before that, I would usually use [`Option::as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut):

```
impl Foo {
    fn send(&mut self) {
        if let Some(x) = self.stream.as_mut() {
            *x += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

### Other options

As Vladimir Matveev points out (again!), `map` is usually used to *transform* data, not for side effects (which I agree with). You could instead use `iter_mut` (or the shorthand of `&mut collection`), as I feel that iteration is usually for side effects. I like this because it means *our* code can avoid having a conditional:

```
impl Foo {
    fn send(&mut self) {
        for x in &mut self.stream {
            *x += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also leverage the `IntoIterator` implementation for `Option`:

```
impl Foo {
    fn send(&mut self) {
        for x in self.stream.as_mut() {
            *x += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For other readers: I got a bit blindsided by the "if let" part of this post. Don't miss `as_mut`, that's the real gem which lets you access the innards of the `Option` without consuming it.

Answer (score 6):

As a follow-up to [@idupree's variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27363383/155423), it is also possible to use if-let syntax:

```
struct Foo {
    stream: Option<i32>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn send(&mut self) {
        if let Some(ref mut x) = self.stream {
            *x = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd also argue that this is more idiomatic than `map()`, because `map()` method is intended for *transforming* an `Option`, not *executing side effects* (and assignment *is* a side effect).

Comment: "`map` is intended for transforming an option" - an interesting point, and I'd probably agree. However, why would you think that `as_mut` exists? I can't think of it being used for anything else...

Comment: Well, it depends on the context where you use it. I certainly can imagine an API which would want to get `Option<&mut T>`. Or it can be used with `Option::or()` and some default target: `self.optional_vector.as_mut().or(&mut self.other_vector).push(123)`. Option is very versatile :)

Comment: I guess perhaps it's the combination of `as_mut` and `map` that doesn't really jive together. Out of curiosity, I did a quick search, and only saw [one other instance](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/84a7615418749d663d54dd9223a15098b834e2a0/src/libcollections/slice.rs#L2033) of a `map` mutating its argument.

Comment: Yeah, and that's probably because this test was written a long time before `if let` has landed :) And it's still feature gated, though this will change soon.

Answer (score 5):

You can match on the `Option` directly, like the following (showing `i32` rather than `TcpStream`):

```
struct Foo {
    stream: Option<i32>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn send(&mut self) {
        match self.stream {
            Some(ref mut x) => {
                *x = 0;
            }
            None => {}
        }
    }
}
```

(Not sure whether that's the most idiomatic way to do it.)