# How to get a mutable variable binding when matching on the value inside Option?

Tags: rust

```
pub fn get_latest_packet(&mut self) -> Option<Packet> {   
     let packet = self.to_send.lock().unwrap().pop_front();
     packet
}
```

where `pub to_send: Arc<Mutex<VecDeque<Packet>>>,`

I'm trying to do this:

```
let packet = smol_socket.get_latest_packet();
match packet {
    Some(packet) => {
         packet.blob.start = 0;
```

I'm getting that I can't because `packet` is not mutable. I can't simply do `let mut packet = ...` because this would make the `Option` mutable, not the packet. Is there a way to `match packet` with it being mutable?

Comment: Try `match &mut packet {`

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Calling a method on a value inside a mutable Option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27361350/155423); [How do I borrow a reference to what is inside an Option<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22282117/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways that work for modifying a value inside a match. It seems there are quite a few subtleties. Here we've collected a variety of solutions

All the examples are based on the following common code

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Packet {
    blob_start:u32
}

pub fn get_latest_packet() -> Option<Packet> {
    Some(Packet{ blob_start:10 })
}

main() {
  let mut packet = get_latest_packet();
  println!("packet = {}", packet);
  // ... match goes here ...
  println!("packet = {}", packet);
}
```

### Matching on a mutable reference with `mut ref` arms.

This was my original version

```
    match &mut packet {
        Some(ref mut packet) => { packet.blob_start = 0; }
        None => { }
    }
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7a4e292cd8dc99837e2a6c8462fa3781)

It was pointed out that this only works due to [match egronomics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html), and is equivalent to:

```
    match &mut packet {
        &mut Some(ref mut packet) => { packet.blob_start = 0; }
        &mut None => { }
    }
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c77f13e6add23c3283a9575e79775f63)

### Matching by value with a `mut ref` arm

You don't need to pass a reference - you can just pass the value, and so long as you take a mutable reference to the contained packet object it works.

```
match packet {
    Some(ref mut packet) => { packet.blob_start = 0; }
    None => { }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eeac4dbacc1ed5f06d25f16a21ae1120)

### Matching with on mutable reference, with default arms

```
match &mut packet {
    Some(packet) => { packet.blob_start = 0; }
    None => { }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=82db23a83a403a4e6fdb48aeb7b0c0e1)

Again this seems to rely on the match ergonomics details.

### Matching by value with `mut` arm.

If you don't need to access the packet option after the match you can use this:

```
match packet {
    Some(mut packet) => {
        packet.blob.start = 0;
        // ... do something with the packet ...
    }
}
```

In this case, you don't need the `mut` on the packet option either.
[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1326ccb8db8ddb0c4eb3d27977c1fa0e)

Answer (score -1):

What you almost certainly want is simply something along the lines of:

```
packet.map(|inner| {
    inner.blob.start = 0;
    inner
});
```

Using [`Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map). In this case, the function that is passed the value that be contained in the `Option` owns the value, and as such is free to do with it as it pleases.

Comment: But packet is not iterateable, it's cimply a stuct that holds a blob, which is a simple struct also

Comment: Zorf means `let packet = smol_socket.get_latest_packet().map(|inner|{inner.blob.start = 0; inner})` I think. You're mapping the `Option` not the `Packet`.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson oh ok. But actually I was making a simplification of the problem. I actually need to check somethings inside the packet before to then set the start